# Simulate layers/undo in multiresolution sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

For a final detail pass on my models I add a multiresolution modifier and subdivide a few times, and then paint in details with alphas. However it's a destructive workflow since there are no layers, if you don't like how a panel line turned out later on-- you reset the mesh? Is there anything you can do besides make a bunch of duplicates of the mesh at various points?